# ¿Cómo ocultar y mostrar App Bar al hacer scroll en WebView?

Tags: android, animación, webview-android

Me gustaría saber como poder ocultar la `AppBar` de una `Activity` al hacer scroll hacia abajo y volver a mostrarla al subir. Es un efecto que tienen muchas aplicaciones en android como Youtube, WhatsApp o Twitter. En mi caso tengo un `WebView` y me gustaría que este efecto se aplicase al hacer scroll sobre el `Webview`.

Comment: Tal vez esto te pueda ayudar https://mzgreen.github.io/2015/02/15/How-to-hideshow-Toolbar-when-list-is-scroling(part1)/

Comment: Gracias, voy a probar ese [ejemplo](https://mzgreen.github.io/2015/02/15/How-to-hideshow-Toolbar-when-list-is-scroling(part1)/) y mirar si puedo implementarlo con un webview @BrandoT.

Comment: Aquí hay un ejemplo https://github.com/RameshBhupathi/CollapsingToolbar-With-Webview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

usted puede hacer esto usando la biblioteca de diseño CoordinatorLayout y NestedScrollView, no es necesario usar código Java. Aquí el código:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

usted puede jugar con diferentes comportamientos: layout_scrollFlags y fitsSystemWindows